# Openssl installation using HomeBrew fails giving a make error

Tags: linux, macos, homebrew

I am using HomeBrew as a package manager.
The operating system that I am using is Mountain Lion.
I just tried to install openssl using the command : brew install openssl
What I am getting is the following error :

```
==> Downloading http://openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1c.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/openssl-1.0.1c.tar.gz
==> perl ./Configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1c --openssldir=/usr/local/etc/openssl zlib-dynamic shared d
==> make
==> make test
==> make install MANDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1c/share/man MANSUFFIX=ssl
created directory `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1c/lib/engines'
created directory `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1c/lib/pkgconfig'
created directory `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1c/include'
created directory `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1c/include/openssl'
make: *** [install_sw] Error 13

Error: openssl did not build
Logs: /Users/Administrator/Library/Logs/Homebrew/openssl/
```

Any ideas on how to overcome this?
Thank you.

Comment: What does the log say? Have you updated Homebrew to the latest version?

Comment: Yes brew is the latest version (using 'brew update')

Comment: There are 4 log files but they're too big to post them here.

Comment: You can just post the most relevant lines or paste them [somewhere else](http://paste.ubuntu.com/)

Answer (score 3):

I had this error on my Mac 10.8.4

> brew install openssl
>
> created directory `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1e/include/openssl'
>   make: *** [install_sw] Error 13

Follow these steps to resolve it  :

1. Create a directory if it's not exist

   > sudo mkdir /usr/local/etc/openssl
2. Change the rights. Replace  and  with your name and group (e.g. serge:admin)

   > sudo chown -R <username>:<group> /usr/local/etc/openssl/
3. Repeat openssl installation

   > brew install openssl
4. Install curl-ca-bundle

   > brew install curl-ca-bundle

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a user write permissions error, but checking the log will verify.

See gist for more details: https://gist.github.com/devinbrown/5084433